# How to change a tuple into array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

Let's say I have a tuple `t = (1,2,3,4)`. What's the simple way to change it into Array?

I can do something like this,

```
array = []
for i in t:
    array.append(i)
```

But I prefer something like x.toArray() or something.

Comment: If you're passing your "array" (list) to a function that wants an iterable, virtually all of them will happily take a `list`, `tuple`, `numpy.array`, `yourawesomeiterabletype`, whatever.

Comment: First, Python doesn't have "array"s.  It has sequences, including `list` and `tuple`.  Why do you want to change one sequence into another?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to convert a tuple to a *list* (as you seem to want) use this:

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3, 4)   # t is the tuple (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> l = list(t)        # l is the list [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In addition I would advise against using `tuple`as the name of a variable.

Comment: +1. Correct answer and apt advice against using names of built in functions as variable names.

Comment: +1 As simple as this answer seems, it is not always obvious to n00bs in the Python world.